# template deduction failed for std::plus

Tags: c++, templates

The following code defines an `operator+` between `std::array` of arbitrary type. The implementation consists in defining an auxiliary routine `op2` that takes a generic callable operator and applies it to every element of the array, via template recursion.

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T, N> operator+(const std::array<T, N>& lhs, const std::array<T, N>& rhs);

template <std::size_t Index = 0, typename T, std::size_t N, class F>
void op2(const std::array<T, N>& lhs, const std::array<T, N>& rhs, std::array<T, N>& res, F&& op);

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T, N> operator+(const std::array<T, N>& lhs, const std::array<T, N>& rhs)
{
    std::array<T, N> res;
    op2(lhs, rhs, res, std::plus{});
    return res;
}

template <std::size_t Index, typename T, std::size_t N, class F>
void op2(const std::array<T, N>& lhs, const std::array<T, N>& rhs, std::array<T, N>& res, F&& op)
{
    std::get<Index>(res) = op(std::get<Index>(lhs), std::get<Index>(rhs));
    if constexpr (Index < (N - 1))
        op2<Index + 1>(lhs, rhs, res, std::forward<F>(op));
}


template <std::size_t N>
void print_array(const std::array<int, N>& a)
{
    for (int x : a)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main(){
    std::array<int, 3> a{1, 2, 3};
    std::array<int, 3> b{2, 2, 1};
    
    print_array(a + b);

    std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 2> c{a, b};
    std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 2> d{a, b};
    
    auto x = c + d; // Error: no match for call to std::plus<void>


    return 0;
}
```

See it [Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcd6128b012eddf6).

The first part works fine and computes the sum of the arrays of int `a` and `b`.

Next, `c` and `d` are `std::array` of `std::array<int,3>`. The program fails to compile because it cannot find a match for `std::plus` between components of `c` and `d`, that is, `std::plus::operator()` cannot understand how to sum two `std::array<int, 3>`.

A workaround is to define `operator+` as

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T, N> operator+(const std::array<T, N>& lhs, const std::array<T, N>& rhs)
{
    std::array<T, N> res;
    op2(lhs, rhs, res, [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return lhs + rhs; });
    return res;
}
```

See it [Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c62fd0a7360424c).

Accordind to the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus_void) `std::plus=std::plus<void>` should simply return the sum result with parameter and return type deduced, pretty much similar to what the anonymous lambda does.

Why the solution with `std::plus` does not compile?

Comment: Don't know it it's related, but your code works with `std::plus<void>` specialization: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus_void. Your _possible implementation_ refers to the primary template.

Comment: @DanielLangr `std::plus{}` does give the `std::plus<void>` specialization. No?

Comment: @DanielLangr ```std::plus<void>{}``` [does not seem to work](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53d2c3515a78e02a) either

Comment: @DanielLangr Care to explain your comment? *your code works with std::plus<void> specialization*. The code uses `std::plus{}`. I'm lost.

Comment: @francesco `std::plus<>{}` is `std::plus<void>{}`. Check the default template argument.

Comment: @super OP referred to the possible implementation of the `operator()` of the primary template. But in their code, the primary template is not instantiated. The `<void>` specialization is instantiated. That possible implementation is thus irrelevant here.

Comment: @DanielLangr Ah, ok. I thought you where saying that the code does work if you use `std::plus<void>`. Any idea why it would not work with `std::plus<void>` but it does work with a seamingly identical [self-defined alternative](https://godbolt.org/z/eK4Y1o)?

Comment: @DanielLangr ahhh, ok. I corrected.

Comment: As an aside, the normal thing would be avoiding recursion and going with [`std::make_index_sequence`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and folding.

Comment: @Deduplicator Why should that be different? The recursion above is resolved at compile time.

Comment: @francesco But if it's a `std::array<T, N>`, that's still about `N` instantiations, which take time and resources, and *might* run into a limit to avoid runaway instantiation before exhausting those. Using an index_sequence and fold-expressions goes far easier on those accounts. Also, that way you can avoid needless default-initialization of the result, which matters for most more complex types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same problem occurs in the following simplified demo:

```
std::array<int, 3> a{1, 2, 3};
std::array<int, 3> b{2, 2, 1};

print_array(std::plus{}(a, b));
```

Internally, `std::plus` invokes `operator+`. But since it is invoked **in the `std::namespace`**, it may not find your custom `operator+` defined outside of this namespace.

---

Generally, operators for some class should be defined in the namespace where that class is defined. But in the case of `std::array`, this is not possible.